# Eclipse PDE build does not call customBuildCallbacks.xml

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pde

I'm trying to get my PDE build script to invoke my customBuildCallbacks.xml. I've added

```
# build.properties
customBuildCallbacks=customBuildCallbacks.xml
```

and copied the customBuildCallbacks.xml file from the PDE build plugin, but it's still not called. The only reference to customBuildCallbacks I get (with -verbose) is a note

```
[java] Override ignored for property "customBuildCallbacks"
```

What I'm trying to do is to run FindBugs on the compiled Jars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you copy it? In [Feature and Plug-in custom build steps](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_custom_callbacks.htm), it says:

> To use custom targets, a feature or plug-in must define the property `customBuildCallbacks` in its `build.properties` file; the value of this property is the location of an xml file, relative to the root of the `feature/plug-in`, containing the custom targets.
>   If the `xml` file is located elsewhere, use the property `customBuildCallbacks.buildpath` to set the directory to use.

May be the "Override ignored" message is for:

"you have overridden customBuildCallbacks, but I (the PDE) cannot find it"?

---

Note: [Andrew Niefer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84728/andrew-niefer) mentions in the comments [bug 165768](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=165768), a design error about customBuildCallbacks since eclipse 3.2.1 (and still open to this day).

> 2 plugins, both use the same customBuildCallbacks.xml, with in both plugins `build.properties`:

```
 customBuildCallbacks=../mydefaultcallbacks/customBuildCallbacks.xml
```

Then you have a 3th plugin, that shall use different callbacks, so in this plugins `build.properties` you write:

```
 customBuildCallbacks=./customBuildCallbacks.xml
```

And then you have a feature, that shall use callbacks as well, but **whatever you
write in this features `build.properties`**, you will end up with this message:

```
[available] DEPRECATED - <available> used to override an existing property.
[available]   Build file should not reuse the same property name for different values.
```

Andrew himself commented in 2006:

> It appears that the plugin's `build.xml` is inheriting the `customBuildCallbacks` property from the feature.

Comment: Thanks. I was having the customBuildCallbacks.xml in the same directory as the PDE build.properties, which wasn't even one of the plugins to build. Moving it to a plugin works much better.

Comment: The "override ignored" may be related to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=165768.  In that bug we still see the custom targets getting called despite the warning.

Comment: @Andrew: thank you for this update. I have completed my answer.

Comment: I'll probably opt for skipping customBuildCallbacks entirely, and run FindBugs on the packaged product instead.